# I can't start ubuntu-desktop on server. Getting Error

Tags: 16.04, drivers, server, vga

I installed `ubuntu-desktop` on Ubuntu server. Every time  I run `startx` I get the following errors:

```
[   124.958] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[   124.959] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   124.960] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   124.961] Current Operating System: Linux NY-QNS-SRV01 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64
[   124.962] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic root=/dev/mapper/NY--QNS--SRV01--vg-root ro
[   124.964] Build Date: 02 November 2016  10:06:10PM
[   124.965] xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   124.966] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[   124.967]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   124.968] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   124.972] (==) Log file: "/home/moses/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Feb 26 07:28:45 2017
[   124.972] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   124.973] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   124.973] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   124.973] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   124.973] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   124.973] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   124.973] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   124.973] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   124.973] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   124.973] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   124.973] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   124.973]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   124.973] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   124.973]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   124.973] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   124.973]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   124.973] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
[   124.973]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   124.973] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   124.973]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   124.973] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   124.973]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   124.973] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    built-ins
[   124.973] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   124.973] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   124.973] (II) Loader magic: 0x558e3d961dc0
[   124.973] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   124.973]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   124.973]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[   124.973]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[   124.973]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[   124.974] (++) using VT number 2

[   124.976] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[   124.977] (--) PCI:*(0:4:3:0) 102b:0532:15d9:0624 rev 10, Mem @ 0xfa000000/16777216, 0xfb800000/16384, 0xfb000000/8388608
[   124.978] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   124.978] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   124.979] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   124.979]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   124.979]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[   124.979] (==) AIGLX enabled
[   124.979] (==) Matched mga as autoconfigured driver 0
[   124.979] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[   124.979] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[   124.979] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[   124.979] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   124.979] (II) LoadModule: "mga"
[   124.979] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mga
[   124.979] (II) UnloadModule: "mga"
[   124.979] (II) Unloading mga
[   124.979] (EE) Failed to load module "mga" (module does not exist, 0)
[   124.979] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   124.979] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   124.979] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   124.979]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
[   124.979]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   124.979]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[   124.979] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   124.980] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[   124.980] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   124.980] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   124.980] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[   124.980] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   124.980] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[   124.980] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   124.980] (II) Unloading vesa
[   124.980] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[   124.980] (==) Matched mga as autoconfigured driver 0
[   124.980] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[   124.980] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[   124.980] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[   124.980] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   124.980] (II) LoadModule: "mga"
[   124.980] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mga
[   124.980] (II) UnloadModule: "mga"
[   124.980] (II) Unloading mga
[   124.980] (EE) Failed to load module "mga" (module does not exist, 0)
[   124.980] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   124.980] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   124.980] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   124.980]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
[   124.980]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   124.980]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[   124.980] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   124.980] (II) Unloading modesetting
[   124.980] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[   124.980] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   124.981] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[   124.981] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   124.981] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   124.981] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[   124.981] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   124.981] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[   124.981] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   124.981] (II) Unloading vesa
[   124.981] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[   124.981] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   124.981] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   124.981] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   124.981] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   124.981] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   124.981] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   124.981] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[   124.981] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   124.981] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   124.981] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   124.981] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   124.981] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[   124.981] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   124.981] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   124.981] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   124.981] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/moses/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   124.981] (EE) 
[   125.121] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I also installed lightdm.
when I run

```
lspci -nnk | grep 
VGA compatible controller MGA G200eW,
```

I have a [Supermicro X9SCL](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C202_C204/X9SCL.cfm) motherboard with integrated graphics.
I have searched multiple forms and tried a couple of solutions, but I am stuck.

Comment: Your motherboard has *BMC integrated Matrox G200* graphics. You may need this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man4/mga.4.html

Comment: Thank you @CelticWarrior, is this a package I should install kind of confused, noob here

Comment: It's a driver so yes, it's a package.

Comment: How do I get it though, apt-get or https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/xserver-xorg-video-mga

Comment: You don't need a PPA because it's in the repositories already. Also prefer `apt` instead of `apt-get` for any 16.04+.

Comment: is this the package name?
xserver-xorg-video-mga
so it should be apt install xserver-xorg-video-mga

Comment: Yes, I think so. Try and you'll see if it works after rebooting. If not please edit and update the information in your question.